# Performance of programs when run under docker containers: same or slower?

Tags: docker

I am using a Docker image built upon ubuntu that contains standard pieces of software that I will be needing in my work in the coming months.

Suppose I have a time-consuming program for sorting a billion numbers written in C++. Say I want to compare the performance of the program-executable on my laptop, against when the executable is run inside of an ubuntu container *on the same laptop*.

On the whole, will there be any difference in performance? For some rough experiments that I've tried, with regards to sorting a million numbers there seems to be no difference in performance. Is this true for other more general computations involving, say, number-crunching or string-processing?

I know docker containers are supposed to be "light-weight" in that they start-up quickly (unlike virtual machines), but I don't know if each container imposes some kind of a "barrier" between the metal and the code running inside the container. Apologies if the last sentence didn't make much sense, I am not very well-versed in containers and virtual machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ObDisclaimer: the only true answer to performance questions is to actually write, run, and measure a benchmark.

ObDisclaimer 2: on modern hardware, don't stress about performance unless you absolutely have a reason to.  People run production-grade workloads written in interpreted languages on virtual machines on shared-tenancy hardware all the time and they don't really notice that it's 100-200x slower than optimized C on bare metal.

---

For the workload you're describing, where it's compute-bound and the data set lives in memory, I would expect the overall performance to be pretty similar between bare metal, Docker, and a virtual machine.

Docker tries hard to be pretty lightweight, and relies heavily on kernel-level support for its magic.  If you're doing file I/O, there will be another layer of indirection mostly within the kernel; if you're doing network I/O, Docker introduces a NAT layer.  (When you say "read `/foo/bar` in Docker, the kernel does some internal indirection to say "oh, you mean this file under `/var/lib/docker` instead".)  If you can measure this difference and it *really* matters to you, then you need to run your application on bare metal; there are likely bigger gains to be had in your application code.

Virtual machines have to simulate all of the "hardware" which can make them slower, especially for disk-bound workloads.  If you're doing file or network I/O it will look like a real write to a disk, but then that disk device is simulated in software.  Again, there's been a lot of work to optimize this over the past decades, and an application-level caching layer can go a long way to improve things (even on bare metal, where the disk and network are the slowest parts of the system).

Either way, pure algorithmic code runs directly on the processor, and the memory controls (ensuring that your process's/VM's memory can't reach another process/VM) are implemented in hardware.